# Make a small change in my code

Tags: vba

I have been using the code below but would like help making 1 small change.  I need to change finding the "15" in the following line of code:“Set Found = SearchCell.Find(What:=15, Lookat:=xlPart)” to find any number with the 000.00 format.

Code currently using;

```vbs
Option Explicit

Sub Found()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim SearchRange As Range, SearchCell, Found As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("F1:F20")
For Each SearchCell In SearchRange
    Set Found = SearchCell.Find(What:=15, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Found.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Set Found = Nothing
Next SearchCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  You have not supplied us all the code, this is obvious by the fact you are using `xlPart` within a .Find function but it's not declared at any point.  " I’ve tried #, #-# and others but no luck." - is far to generic and doesn't provide enough detail of what you actually tried.

Comment: @ramhound I think this question is clear enough, OP wants to find any number; as anyway that's not the right direction to look for, it doesn't matter what exactly has tried.  Important that tried to find the solution! xlPart is a constant in vba, no need to be declared.

Comment: Range.find performs the same action as manual search with ctrl+f; it can't look by number format. You need to loop through your range and check [`Range.NumberFormat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)

Comment: Do numbers have a format?   Or do the cells?

Comment: The cells are formatted 000.00

Answer (score 1):

here is a bit changed code:

```
Sub Found()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim SearchRange As Range, SearchCell As Range
Set SearchRange = ws.Range("F1:F20")
For Each SearchCell In SearchRange
    If SearchCell.NumberFormat = "000.00" Then
        SearchCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next SearchCell
End Sub
```

Comment: @MátéJuhász why is it strange? i've added a screenshot. range F1:F20 contains random numbers without any formating

Comment: yes you are right, i'll correct the code

Comment: yes, it's good now!

Comment: Hi, thank-you guys for your help. I'm off to visit my sister for 1 week but upon my return I will test out the new code and get back to you. Thanks again